# Sequential algorithm with asynchronous events

Tags: qt, signals

I'm currently (re)designing a system which consists of several parts:

- the first part is an entity that (asynchronously) gets frames from a source and fires an event each time a frame is ready – via Qt signal.
- the second part is a GUI that shows the frames in the real-time and is connected to the above signal by a slot
- the last part is frame processor which behavior is best described by sequential algorithm (while, for, etc.) with possibility to respond to several kinds of the signal from GUI.

The main question is **if there are best practices of organizing such code**?

The solution I've come up with and don't like much is: run 4 threads.

- GUI thread which communicates via Qt signals with 3 other threads
- Frame source thread which emits a signal on each frame availability.
- Frame organizer thread which stores frames upon signal and uses QWaitCondition to notify frame processor thread.
- Frame processor thread which calls getNextFrame() from frame organizer.

But I feel it's not a good solution, possibly, due to mixing different paradigms (wait conditions and signals). Additionally, waiting on condition may lead to starvation of the event processing queue.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `QWaitCondition`. The threads should be bare (non-derived) `QThreads`. Put all your code within `QObjects` that are moved to those threads. The frame organizer simply sends signals to frame processor. Signals are delivered across thread boundaries by posting events to the thread's event loop. Those event loops internally use synchronization primitives (mutexes) to seralize access, so there's no need to reinvent the wheel there. QThread's default implementation of `run()` simply spins an event loop, so you don't need to do anything besides instantiating the thread and starting it.

Your code should run, perhaps with reduced performance, with all the QObjects instantiated in the GUI thread. Moving them to separate threads would be done when your benchmarking shows which objects are CPU-bound. There is a sad but necessary exception to this rule: If your camera code can only use blocking APIs provided by the camera driver (APIs that wait for something instead of asynchronously reporting it), then you have no choice but to sacrifice a thread for that. With exception of such dedicated blocking-workaround threads, your application should use about as many threads in total as there are available cores (`QThread::idealThreadCount()`). You would instantiate up to that number of threads, and distribute QObjects among those threads randomly or in a round-robin fashion. Again -- only move QObjects that are CPU-bound. IO bound objects that use non-blocking APis (networking!) don't need that treatment. Sane device drivers (like from http://www.ftdichip.com/) expose asynchronous event notifications that can be converted to signals by [`QWinEventNotifier`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qwineventnotifier.html). It's a private API in Qt 4.x, but works fine in spite of that.

It's really lamentable that a lot of common APIs out there are blocking. Database drivers are a typical example. I ended up porting mysql client driver to use `QTcpSocket`, for example, so that the database wouldn't block the thread that uses it.

Comment: I understand your answer and it contains a lot of useful information for me. However, my main question was how to convert the event-driven paradigm (`frameReady()` events) into sequential processing ( `while( getNextFrame() ) processFrame()`).

I've encountered solutions with starting local event loop (`QEventLoop`) and connecting the desired signal (`frameReady()`) to its `quit()` slot. However that looks ugly to me and as I understood has drawbacks --- can interfere with the normal course of signal-slot processing.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough at my initial formulation.

Comment: To be even more specific, I'd like to be able to express an algorithm:

`frame = wait4goodFrame(); /* calls getNextFrame() internally */
doSmth( frame ); doSmthElse( getNextFrame() );`

instead of processing it in a slot
`void processFrame(frame) { if (weAreWaiting4goodFrame && isGoodFrame(frame)) doSomth( frame );
else if (weAreInStage2)
doSmthElse( frame ); else if ...}`

It's less readable and has a huge boilerplate code.

Comment: Converting event-driven to sequential processing is exactly what you're *not* supposed to do. The readability/boilerplate is minimal unless your code is trivial. The `if (weAreWaiting4goodFrame ...` means that you want a state machine. Those are best expressed directly in a reimplementation of `void customEvent(QEvent*)`. For a rudimentary FSM, simply dispatch to a method pointer, and have one method per state. That's the way to correctly engineer it. Mangling state machines within sequential processing only works initially. As you start handling error recovery etc, the code becomes spaghetti.